# Função de adicionar 1 mês no php falha quando o mês atual não possui dia 31

Tags: php

Neste código *PHP*, estou verificando o tipo de recorrência de uma atividade contida numa lista de atividades, e adicionando 1 mês quando é recorrência mensal, 2 meses quando é recorrência bimestral e etc.

```php
if($recorrencia == "UNICA")
        return;
    elseif($recorrencia == "MENSALMENTE")
        $data_vencimento = date('Y-m-d H:m:s', strtotime('+1 month', strtotime($atividade['DT_VENCIMENTO']))); /*1 mês*/
    elseif($recorrencia == "BIMESTRALMENTE")
        $data_vencimento = date('Y-m-d H:m:s', strtotime('+2 month', strtotime($atividade['DT_VENCIMENTO']))); /*2 mês*/
    elseif($recorrencia == "TRIMESTRALMENTE")
        $data_vencimento = date('Y-m-d H:m:s', strtotime('+3 month', strtotime($atividade['DT_VENCIMENTO']))); /*3 mês*/
    elseif($recorrencia == "SEMESTRALMENTE")
        $data_vencimento = date('Y-m-d H:m:s', strtotime('+6 month', strtotime($atividade['DT_VENCIMENTO']))); /*6 mês*/    
    elseif($recorrencia == "ANUALMENTE")
        $data_vencimento = date('Y-m-d H:m:s', strtotime('+12 month', strtotime($atividade['DT_VENCIMENTO']))); /*12 mês*/
```

Porém, o *PHP* parece que na verdade está **adicionando 30 dias**, pois quando tenho datas como a seguinte:

> 31/05/2019

Após rodar a função, a data passa a ser:

> 01/07/2019

Entendo que seja por que no mês 06 não possui dia 31, pois todos os outros dias adicionam corretamente.

Como eu poderia contornar este problema?

Comment: Sem tempo pra escrever uma resposta agora, mas sinto informar que provavelmente terá que fazer um ajuste manual: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5760371

Comment: Não pode usar dias ao invés de mês?

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38226215/how-to-include-the-end-date-in-a-dateperiod . Pesquise sobre DateInterval e DatePeriod

Comment: Se falha nos meses de 30, então também em fevereiro!?

Comment: @hkotsubo vou tentar implementar aqui algo parecido com esse do link

Comment: @EdwardRamos daria no mesmo.

Comment: @rbz Sim, exato.

Comment: @Denied Testou em quais versões do PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenho a seguinte sugestão, que acredito que resolve seu problema de forma clara.

```
if($recorrencia == "UNICA") return;

$recorrencias           = [
    'MENSALMENTE'       => 1,
    'BIMESTRALMENTE'    => 2,
    'TRIMESTRALMENTE'   => 3,
    'SEMESTRALMENTE'    => 6,
    'ANUALMENTE'        => 12,
];
$meses                  = $recorrencias[ $recorrencia ];
$data_vencimento        = new \DateTime( $atividade['DT_VENCIMENTO'] );
$ano                    = $data_vencimento->format( 'Y' );
$mes                    = $data_vencimento->format( 'm' );
$dia                    = $data_vencimento->format( 'd' );

// Adiciona a quantidade de meses pretendida, mas define o dia como o último do mês
$data_vencimento->setDate($ano, $mes + $meses + 1, 0);

// Se o dia pretendido for menor que o último dia do mês, então faz a correção
if ( $dia < $data_vencimento->format( 'd' ) ) $data_vencimento->setDate( $ano, $mes + $meses, $dia );

$data_vencimento        = $data_vencimento->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
```

Comment: Segui esse raciocínio na minha solução.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro, a pergunta é: o que "adicionando 1 mês". 1 mês = 30 dias? 28 dias? 29 dias? 31?

O seguinte código:

```
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2019-01-31 +1 month"));
```

Tem o seguinte resultado:

```
2019-03-03
```

Está correto pois a função converte a segunda parte da data (o mês) para o seguinte), que seria 31/02/2019. Como não existe 31 dias em Fevereiro e este ano o mês teve 28 dias, são acrescentados os dias faltantes, jogando a data para o dia 3 de Março (se fizer o mesmo teste com 2016, verá que a data final é 2 de Março porque Fevereiro teve 29 dias em 2016).

Diante disso, penso que deveria reformular sua pergunta e/ou necessidade.

- Se deseja acrescentar 30 (ou 60 ou 90 dias) a data que possui, simplesmente some o número de dias de acordo com sua necessidade.
- Se você deseja simplesmente dizer que "bimestralmente" é hoje + 2 meses, acrescente 2 ao mês corrente.

Existem outras abordagens também, porém todas elas dependem da resposta a pergunta "adicionado 1 mês" para contextualizar corretamente.

Comment: "*Está correto*" é relativo. Há outras linguagens e API's que ajustam automaticamente para o último dia do mês (assim, 2019-01-31 + 1 mês = 2019-02-28 - [em Java é assim](https://ideone.com/kCgogW), em [C# também](https://ideone.com/m3VRAo), e em Python o módulo `dateutil` [também faz esse ajuste](https://repl.it/repls/PersonalNecessaryTranslations)). Não existe "correto" em aritmética de datas, porque não há uma norma "oficial" (como há na matemática, por exemplo). O que temos são diferentes decisões de implementação, cada uma com seus prós e contras.

Comment: Pessoalmente eu prefiro esse ajuste, afinal, se somar 1 mês a uma data em janeiro, por que o resultado deveria ser em março? (há - ou deveria haver - toda uma semântica na operação "somar X meses", que deveria ser mantida de forma consistente - embora eu entenda esses ajustes que o PHP faz, já que muitas outras linguagens também o fazem - por ex: JavaScript) Mas como eu disse, são decisões de implementação de cada linguagem, e temos que conviver com elas...

Comment: Não, não é relativo. O assunto é PHP e não Java. MySQL também faz o mesmo e isso poderia inclusive ser feito diretamente em nível de BD, mas eu me atentei ao pressuposto em questão, sem fazer variações, haja visto que foi perguntado especificamente sobre uma função de PHP e a resposta é correta para dita função. Especular se a galinha ou o ovo vieram em primeiro não agrega nada na resposta ao colega.

Comment: Só estou dizendo que o resultado depende de como cada linguagem escolheu implementar a aritmética de datas. O PHP escolheu de um jeito, outras linguagens escolheram de outro. Dizer que somente um deles é o correto pode passar a impressão que todas as demais estão erradas, e eu só quis enfatizar isso: que nenhuma está "mais correta" que outras, são apenas decisões de implementação com as quais temos que conviver, e ajustar o código de acordo. Note que em nenhum momento insinuei que sua resposta está errada, só questionei a afirmação de que o comportamento do PHP é o "jeito correto".